# Rails command not working on Windows command line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I installed Ruby and Rails and set-up the PATH to "C:\Rails\Ruby2.3.0\bin", but when I try to run commands with `rails`, I get the error message:

```
The System cannot find the path specified.
```

I am able to run commands using `ruby`, and `rails` works if I use GitBash. How do I make it work on my normal command line?

Comment: We need more information. How did you install Ruby and Rails? How did you set your PATH?

Comment: Navigate in Windows Explorer to `C:\Rails\Ruby2.3.0\bin`. Does the directory exist? What files are there?

Comment: @theTinMan I installed ruby and rails from http://railsinstaller.org/en. It automatically added to user variables PATH. Since it was not working I also added the same path to Path under System variables. Still not working.

Comment: @tibsar Directory exists. Consists of many files like bundle.bat, ruby.exe, gem, sqlite3.exe, rails.bat

Comment: Have you restarted your terminal? What terminal are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem here, installed the same way. Couldn't even run rails commands on GitBash, only way was going in `C:\Rails\Ruby2.3.0\bin`through cmd and typing, for example, `ruby rails new projectname`. The `rails new projectname`wouldn't work even in these conditions.

What I did was going in the Command Prompt with Ruby and Rails and entered `gem install rails` (which did not work on cmd). I also did `gem install bundle`. Both installed successfully and that fixed all consoles for me: cmd, GitBash (wasn't working for me), Command Prompt with Ruby and Rails and even cmder works with Rails now.

Hope this helps you.
Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a simple question of locating the rails executable on Windows, then on later installs that use msys64 instead of DevKit, you'll find rails at the following folder:

```
c:\msys64\o-rdoc
```

Add this to your PATH or execute from that folder.

Your path may vary on 32-bit systems or if you changed the default install folder.